# undefined reference to vector<String> g++ linker error

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, undefined

I have compiled the dependent files of my source file mycpp.c and linked the files in the order which they have used .All the dependant files are available in the same folder.

```
   **//Compilation**
     $ g++  -c -w -Wno-deprecated String.c Vector.c DPStream.c CJ_Base.c mycpp.c
     **//Linking**
     $ g++ -g -o myexe String.o Vector.o DPStream.o CJ_Base.o mycpp.o
Vector.h
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <iomanip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "String.h"
#include "Storage.h"


template <class Object>
class Vector : public Storage{

        public:
                // ctors & dtor
                Vector ();
                Vector (int);
                ~Vector();

                // overloaded operators
                Object& operator[] (int nSubscript);
                void operator<<(Object &);
                void operator<<(char *);

                // access methods
                int  Count(){return _iCurrElem;};
                int  Print(ofstream &);
                void Flush();
                Resize(int);

                int  IsType() {return VectorType;};

        private:
                long _iCurrElem;
                Object *moj;
                long _iUpperBound;

                void _reserve(int);
};
#endif


Vector.c
---------
#include"Vector.h"

template <class Object>
Vector<Object>::Vector ()
{
   moj = new Object[3];
}

template <class Object>
Vector<Object>::Vector (int e)
{
moj = new Object[e];
}

template <class Object>
Vector<Object>::~Vector ()
{
  delete[] moj;
} 

template <class Object>
Vector<Object>::operator<<(Object &)
{
//stmt
}

template <class Object>
Vector<Object>::operator<<(char* ch)
{
//stmt
}

template <class Object>
Vector<Object>::Print(ofstream &foutput)
{
//stmt
}
```

Included the header files in the below orde in mycpp.h

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <iomanip.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include "String.h"
#include "Vector.h"
#include "DPStream.h"
#include "CJ_Base.h"
```

But still the g++ compiler throws an error
 *Pasted below the link error*

```
        DPStream.o: In function `DPStream::operator<<(Vector<String>&)':
    DPStream.c:(.text+0x396): undefined reference to `Vector<String>::Print(std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
    mycpp.o: In function `mycpp::ProcessFile()':
    mycpp.o:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `Vector<String>::operator<<(String&)'
    mycpp.o:(.text+0x2e5): undefined reference to `Vector<String>::operator<<(char*)'
    mycpp.o:(.text+0x310): undefined reference to `Vector<String>::Flush()'
    mycpp.o:(.text+0x32b): undefined reference to `Vector<String>::operator<<(String&)'
    mycpp.o:(.text+0x346): undefined reference to `Vector<String>::operator<<(String&
    mycpp.o: In function `mycpp::~mycpp()':
    mycpp.o:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `Vector<String>::operator<<(String&)'
```

Could you please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: #include <iostream.h> should be #include <iostream>.

Comment: or #include <iostream.h> using namespace std;??

Comment: @spin_eight just `<iostream>` , all standard C++ headers have no `.h`. The `.h` variants are pre-standard legacy

Comment: Unrelated: I would recommend against using `-w` in your own code.

Comment: i think if you put the Vector implementation in the h file or include the cpp file into the h file, you should be ok.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore :modification introduces new error /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/backward/iostream.h:52: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant

Comment: @user2040497 different error. Correct way is <iostream>

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : modified #include <iostream.h> to #include <iostream> ,now g++ compiler throws an error                                                                            /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/backward/io‌​stream.h:52: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant

Answer (score 1):

You don't show us where and how `Vector` is defined, but just
a guess: you're compiling a `Vector.c`.  If this file contains
the implementation of a template, you're doing it wrong; the
implementation of a template must be visible when the template
is instantiated.  You can either put it in the header, or
include the source from the header, but you don't compile the
source.

Also, *most* compilers consider a `.c` to be C source, and not
C++.  You almost certainly want to change the names of your
sources to `.cpp` or `.cc`.  While you're at it, I'd change the
names of the pure C++ headers as well.  While ubiquitous, using
the same naming convention for C headers and for pure C++
headers can be confusing.

And finally, the `<name.h>` forms of the C standard headers are
not standard; if they're present (they usually aren't), they
should refer to older, pre-standard versions of the library.
(Judging from your error messages, this is apparently not the
case.)

Comment: :Thanks for the information.I have updated my question i.e. provided the code of "vector.c" and "vector.h" Could you please check and advise me

Answer (score 0):

All your errors are related to template functions.

Remember that when defining a template you must **put the definitions in the header**, not in a `.cpp` file. Other modules need the definition to perform their own instantiations of the template.

So a quick fix would be to do a simple `#include "Vector.c"` at the end of `Vector.h`.

Alternatively put your whole template implementation inside `.h` files.

---

(Also please use `.cpp` not `.c` for C++ source files; using `hpp` for C++ headers is nice too)